# How to load the data to high charts when the listbox value is changed

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Hi i am new to high charts and angularjs. i am trying to develop a page, where it contain two listbox and one chart. the two listbox contain x-axis categories and y-axis series name. when you select one value in each listbox and click on button. then it need to plot the graph based on selection. can anyone please help me in that.

My code

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="float: left">
<select size="10" id="myselection"  ng-model="selectedColors" ng-options="c.name for c in colors" style="width: 150px"></select>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1" style="float: left">
<select size="10" id="myselection" ng-model="selectedColors" ng-options="c.name for c in colors" style="width: 150px"></select>
 </div>
<div style="float: right; margin-top: -260px; margin-right: 50px">
<b>Chart type: </b>
    <select ng-model='chartType' class='input'>
      <option value="pie">Pie</option>
      <option value="bar">Bar</option>
      <option value="line">Line</option>
      <option value="point">Point</option>
      <option value="area">Area</option>
    </select>
    <span ng-show="chartType==='pie'"><b>Radius</b> <input ng-model="config.innerRadius" size="4"></span>
    <span ng-show="chartType==='line'">
      <b>Legend Position:</b>
      <select ng-options="opt for opt in ['lineEnd','traditional']" ng-model="config.lineLegend"></select>
    </span>
    <p></p>
    <div class='charts'>
      <div ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="data" ac-config="config" id='chart' class='chart'></div>
    </div>
```

not getting how to pass the listbox selected value to javascript to select the category and series.

Comment: Have you tried to set ng-click on the item and then call custom fucntion which print chart ?

Comment: No can u guide me how it works?

Comment: [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)